# Hive not creating CSV file correctly

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I am trying to export the Hive results to a file located on Amazon s3.

But the result file has some unrecognized characters like square etc.

The type of the result file format is binary/octet-stream and not csv.

I am not getting whey it is not able to create a csv file.

The version of hive used is hive-0.8.1.

I am putting the steps I followed below.

By the way the hive is used from an instance launched by Amazon EMR.

```
 create table test_csv(employee_id bigint, employee_name string, employee_designation string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;

  insert overwrite table test_csv select employee_id , employee_name , employee_designation from employee_details;

  INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3n://<path_to_s3_bucket>' SELECT * from test_csv;
```

Can you please let me know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: check wheather select query giving proper result.then try insert

Comment: yes the select query given proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For I know, `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY` will always use ctrl-A('\001') as delimiter. Direct copy of file with your table data would be the best solution. GL.

Comment: Try this: hadoop distcp hdfs://<hive data> s3://<path_to_s3_bucket>/

Answer (score 1):

You can export data from Hive via the command line:

`hive -e 'select * from foo;' > foo.tsv`

You could probably pipe through sed or something to transform the tabs into commas, we just used TSVs for everything.

Comment: This method would work same as `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY`, all fields delimiters will be changed to ctrl-A. Let's hope it would be changed in next HIVE release.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it uses tabs for delimiters when you do it this way. At least, the guys I pass the files on to have never complained.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening the Hive warehouse directory in HDFS to your output so as to check how the data is stored there?

I think this line is not required to be executed

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3n://<path_to_s3_bucket>' SELECT * from test_csv;
```

rather you can directly do a **"dfs -get"**

Comment: so instead of s3 I should put the hdfs file path in INSERT query? And if I put the hdfs path will hive be able to access that?

Comment: @Sam hive can successfully write to hdfs path,you can use that

Comment: @Balaswami vaddeman but I want to store the result to s3 and not to hdfs.

Comment: create external table with s3 path,then insert your select results into that table ,may be it works